# Find $E[X]$ from the function given

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, expected-value

[image: HELP MEEEEEEE]

From the given probability function of $X$, compute $E[X]$. I know the answer is 8, but not sure how to show the series converges to 8 in this case.

Comment: I could be wrong but say $Y \sim Geometric(1/2)$ and $E[Y] = 2$ and X = 6+Y so $E[X] = 6+2 =8 $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${\cal E}[x] = {\sum\limits_{x=7}^\infty x\ 2^{6-x} \over \sum\limits_{x=7}^\infty 2^{6-x}} = {8 \over 1} = 8.$$

To perform the sum in the numerator:

Let $y = x-6$ to get:

$$\sum\limits_{y=1}^\infty (y+6) 2^{-y} = 6 \sum\limits_{y=1}^\infty 2^{-y} + \sum\limits_{y=1}^\infty y 2^{-y} = 6 + 2 = 8.$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer David. I have a question... why is the denominator necessary... correct me if I'm wrong but that is showing it's a pmf that adds to $1$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes... it *happens* to sum to $1$ since you gave it as a true $PDF$, but in some problems the given function will not, so you must normalize.  You can ignore it here, if you like.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: But how do you know that the numerator converges to 8?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How did the second summation term turns to 2?

Comment: See one answer, below.

Answer (score 7):

Letting $Y = X-6$ we have:

$$p_Y(y) = 2^{-y} \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } y \in \mathbb{N}.$$

This random variable has a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) $Y \sim \text{Geom}(\tfrac{1}{2})$ so we have $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 2$, which then gives the corresponding expected value $\mathbb{E}(X) = 6 + 2 = 8$.  If you want to formally derive the expected value of this distribution you can do so like this:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(Y) 
&= \sum_{y} y \cdot p_Y(y) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty y \cdot 2^{-y} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{z=1}^y 2^{-y} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{z=1}^\infty \sum_{y=z}^\infty 2^{-y} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{z=1}^\infty 2^{-z} \sum_{y=0}^\infty 2^{-y} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \Bigg( \sum_{z=0}^\infty 2^{-z} \Bigg) \Bigg( \sum_{y=0}^\infty 2^{-y} \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \times 2 \times 2 = 2. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

(This working uses repeated application of the sum of an infinite geometric series.)

Comment: Very nice!!!!! +1